# Calculate with date, without import dateutil

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
date1 = datetime.strptime(str('2011-08-15 12:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date2 = datetime.strptime(str('2012-02-15'), '%Y-%m-%d')
r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
r.months
```

The code above does the trick for me but i don't want to import dateutil. Does anyone have an example for me without looping?

I want to deduct two dates from each other and i want to know the difference in months between the two dates in whole months.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/difference-between-two-time-intervals-in-python

Comment: Why are you so reluctant to make the necessary import? It seems fishy.

Comment: Because i'm not allowed to import the module at work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this post helps: [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

simply do a substraction on two datetime obj, then you can get what detail you want in the diff.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, your code outputs to: `5` which means, as suggested in the comments, that you are probably interested in the duration of each month and you do not want to round your results. Unfortunately the `timedelta` object will not work for you in this case because by definition, a time difference does not hold the information you need to obtain the duration of the months of interest to you.

You should probably take a look here:
[Python: Difference of 2 datetimes in months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015587/python-difference-of-2-datetimes-in-months)
where they discuss a solution using `calendar` instead of `dateutil`.

Otherwise, if you are happy with an approximated (and rounded) estimate, you could go close enough by doing:

```
DAYS_PER_MONTH = 30  # or 365.0 / 12.0 for more precision
datetime_diff = date2 - date1
print(datetime_diff.days / DAYS_PER_MONTH)  # '//' for floored result
```

If you want to get back to some code that works with your data (but not with all data, because of e.g. leap years, leap seconds, etc.) have a look here:

```
MONTH_NUM_DAYS = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
YEAR_LENGTH = 365.25  # average year duration, including leap years

def num_days_in_months(
        begin_month, end_month, month_duration=MONTH_NUM_DAYS):
    begin_month, end_month = sorted((begin_month, end_month))
    return sum(month_duration[begin_month:end_month])

def get_num_months(begin_date, end_date, num_days_per_year=YEAR_LENGTH):
    begin_month = begin_date.month
    end_month = end_date.month
    month_diff = abs(end_month - begin_month)
    num_days = (end_date - begin_date).days
    num_days_within_year = num_days % num_days_per_year
    num_months = num_days // num_days_per_year
    num_days_max = num_days_in_months(begin_month, end_month)
    print(num_months, month_diff)
    if num_days_within_year < num_days_max:
        num_months += month_diff - 1
    else:
        num_months += month_diff
    return num_months
```

Comment: It's 5 months because the delta is actually 5 mos, 30.5 days. The time in the first day is 12:00, in the second one it is implicitly 0:00. You would get 6 mos if the times were the same (either omit the first time or set the second one to 12:00, for example)

Comment: I see.. I obviously overlooked that the expected behavior was not `round(num_months)`, but rather `floor(num_months)`, and you are interested in the exact duration of each month, in which case the `timedelta` object is not an option there, so there is probably not a solution that does not involve cycling through the duration of each month

Comment: I assumed you knew about the floor operation because that is what you do with `//` in your answer too.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: @norok2 could you give exaqmple dates with your code please?

Comment: The code above will not work if you want to get `5`, because the `datetime_diff` will have no information about the start and end dates.
The time difference is _on average_ 6 months and that is what you will get with an _average_ definition of month. If need something that works on your scenario, you have to do something different, and would probably involve a (more or less hidden) loop... probably your best shot is just to copy the code from `dateutils` if you want your result to be robust enough...

Comment: I have actually edited the code so that there is some code that does the trick but should not be 100% robust, as there is no proper support for leap years, leap seconds, etc., but it works a relatively large number of situations.