# calculate age in openerp

Tags: odoo

I want make code can calculate age

```
def _compute_age(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, field_value, context=None):
    records = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    result={}
    for r in records:
        age=0
        if r.date_birth:
            d = strptime(r.date_birth,"%Y-%m-%d")
            count = date(d[0],d[1],d[2])-date.today()
            age = count.days/365 
        result[r.id] = age
    return result
```

but wrong **'cursor' object has no attribute 'browse'**, what the problem ?

P.S :
This my new code

```
def _compute_age(self, cr, uid, ids,field_name,field_value,arg, context=None):
    records = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    result = {}
    for r in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        age=0
        if r.date_birth:
            print date_birth
            age = (datetime.now()-datetime.strptime(r.date_birth,"%Y-%m-%d")).days/365.25
        result[r.id] = age 

    return result
_columns = {
    'date_birth': fields.date('Date of Birth'),
    'age' : fields.function(_compute_age, type='char', method=True, string='Age'),
```

Comment: The problem probably is in the call to the method. Can you post that code?

Comment: can you paste your function field

Comment: if type='char' then provide size too. for example size=64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is not related to the date calculation. You might be using a module incompatible with the version of OpenERP you are using.

You need to provide more details about your module, OpenERP and addons version, and full traceback.

While irrelevant to the error, your age calculation would yield a negative value.

A simpler code would be:

```
from datetime import datetime
...
    if r.date_birth:
        age = (datetime.now()-datetime.strptime(r.date_birth,"%Y-%m-%d")).days/356
```

---

Regarding the new code and error message below, You cannot append to a list by assigning to new index, change `result` to be a dictionary instead; Change `result = []` to `result = {}`

Comment: You surely ment `/365` instead of `/356`. I'm not a fan of this  division by days approach, but if you use it it's more accurate to divide `/365.25`. But IMHO it's best to count months and divide by 12. I a posted a function for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9033133/959570).

Comment: The 2nd version has incorrect call to browse(). You should call self.browse() as calling browse() should be undefined in the function context.

Comment: already I tried. but same error. like this right `records = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context) `

Comment: @MohammadAli I want make, float..., so if we choose 27 - March -1989. in fields age the result "23"

Comment: please help me...this really2 urgent

Answer (score 1):

Following is my code. it returns a string.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime
def _compute_age(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context={}):
    result = {}
    now = datetime.now()
    for r in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
      if r.date_birth:
        dob = datetime.strptime(r.date_birth,'%Y-%m-%d')
        delta=relativedelta (now, dob)
        result[r.id] = str(delta.years) +"y "+ str(delta.months) +"m "+ str(delta.days)+"d" #if you only want date just give delta.years
      else:
        result[r.id] = "No DoB !"
    return result


_columns = {
    'age' : fields.function(_compute_age, method=True, type='char', size=32, string='Age',),
}
```

Comment: sorry...this the error **result[r.id] = "No DoB !"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range**

Comment: sorry my mistake. please change the result=[] to result={}

Answer (score 0):

I created the student module and get the age field from the date of birth field using compute field

models.py

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

class studentimg(models.Model):

     _name = 'studentimg.studentimg'
     name=fields.Char('Student')
     email = fields.Char('Email')
     phone = fields.Char('Phone')
     gender = fields.Selection([('m','Male'),('f','Female')],'Gender')
     is_active =fields.Boolean('Active')
     birth_date=fields.Date('Birth Date')
     age=fields.Char('Age',compute='calculate_age')
     image=fields.Binary()
     mat=fields.Integer('Maths')
     phy=fields.Integer('Physics')
     tot=fields.Integer('Total',compute='_computediff')

     @api.onchange('phy')
     def _computediff(self):
          self.tot = self.mat + self.phy

     def calculate_age(self):
         today = date.today()
         #self.age= today.year -  self.birth_date.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.birth_date.month, self.birth_date.day))
         yr=int(self.birth_date[0:4])
         mt=int(self.birth_date[5:7])
         dt=int( self.birth_date[8:10])
         self.age = today.year - yr - ((today.month, today.day) < (mt, dt))
```

templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record id='student_form_view' model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Student Form View</field>
        <field name="model">studentimg.studentimg</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Student Information">
                <sheet>
                        <field name="image" widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar"/>
                    <h2>
                        <field name="name"/>
                    </h2>
                           <notebook>
                             <page string="Public Information">
                                 <group>
                                          <group string="Contact Information" class="oe_left oe_avatar">
                                           <field name="email"/>
                                           <field name="phone"/>
                                          </group>



                                          <group string="Student Details">
                                             <field name="gender"/>
                                             <field name="is_active"/>
                                          </group>
                                          <group string="DOB">
                                              <field name="birth_date"/>
                                              <field name="age"/>
                                          </group>
                                          <group string="Total Marks">
                                              <field name="mat"/>
                                              <field name="phy"/>
                                              <field name="tot"/>
                                          </group>
                                 </group>
                             </page>
                           </notebook>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
</record>

<record id='student_tree_view' model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Student Tree View</field>
        <field name="model">studentimg.studentimg</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Student Details">
                <field name="image"/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="email"/>
                <field name="phone"/>
                <field name="gender"/>
                <field name="is_active"/>
                <field name="birth_date"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
</record>
<record id="students_students_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
       <field name="name">Students</field>
       <field name="res_model">studentimg.studentimg</field>
       <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
birth_date = fields.Date('Birth Date')
age = fields.Char('Age',compute='_cal_age')

 @api.multi
    @api.depends('birth_date')
    def _cal_age(self):
        today = date.today()
        for record in self:
            age = []
            dob = fields.Date.from_string(record.birth_date)
            gap = relativedelta(today, dob)
            if gap.years > 0:
                record.age = str(gap.years) + ' Years'
            else:
                raise UserError(_('Birth Date must be Low than the Current Date'))
```