# how to handle a date format in mm-yy in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data set where one of the variable is in format 'mm-yy' as below.

```
0    Feb-94
1    Oct-00
2    Jun-00
3    Jan-85
4    Dec-96
........etc
```

I want to change it to a format so that I can calculate how many months between, say Feb-94, and this month (Aug-2015). I am using Python 2.7. If there is no direct conversion possible, could anybody give me a clue (code snippet perhaps) as to how to efficiently perform this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried looking at, perhaps, the `datetime` module?

Comment: I tried to split it by '-' and then convert the month to numbers, for example, Feb to 02 and so forth. But it is getting difficult as I need to convert 94 to 1994 and 01 to 2001 and so on. So it is becoming clunky. I am wondering is there a more easier way of doing it ? I am new to Python, so may be missing modules which could help me.

Comment: [try a little Google on for size](https://www.google.com/#q=python+format+date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803877/1620879). In short, you need to use `datetime.strptime()` from the `datetime` module. In your particular case, this should help:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('Feb-15', '%b-%y')
```

`d` is of type `datetime`. You can then use python to compute time differences. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040338/1620879) provides *a possible way* of computing time differences between two `datetime` objects.

Look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more format options you can use with `strptime`.

Comment: OP's data seems to be month-year not month-day. So `strptime()` format string should be ``%b-%y'`.

Comment: Oops, you are right @mhawke. I guess I glossed over that. I've fixed it in the answer. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert your month-year strings to `datetime` objects, then perform some simple arithmetic:

```
from datetime import datetime

def elapsed_months(date1, date2=datetime.today()):
    return abs(date1.year * 12 + date1.month) - (date2.year * 12 + date2.month)

>>> dt1 = datetime.strptime('Feb-94', '%b-%y')
>>> elapsed_months(dt1)
>>> elapsed_months
258
>>> elapsed_months(datetime.strptime('Aug-15', '%b-%y'))
0
>>> elapsed_months(datetime.strptime('Aug-15', '%b-%y'), datetime.strptime('Aug-18', '%b-%y'))
36
# order of dates does not matter
>>> elapsed_months(datetime.strptime('Aug-18', '%b-%y'), datetime.strptime('Aug-15', '%b-%y'))
36
```