# Calculate time duration using python

Tags: python, date, time, difference, date-difference

```
>>> M1
['month:12;year:2006', 'month:7;year:2010']
>>> M2
['month:5;year:2006', 'month:3;year:2010']
>>> M3
['year:2006'; 'month:4;year:2010']
```

I have 3 list item `M1, M2, M3`

```
M1[0] is the Start date 
M2[0] is the End date
```

is it possible to convert the list this way and perform computations

```
M1 = 12/2006, 7/2010
M2 = 5/2006, 3/2010
M3 = 0/2006, 4/2010
```

What i want is to calculate the difference between them in months like,

```
M1Diff = 43 months
M2Diff =  52 months
M3Diff = 51 months
```

Comment: It is surely possible. What did you try?

Comment: How month can be 0? I mean what is the 0th month?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque , It could make sense that 0 - January, 11 - December. But, He has already 12 which is weird :P

Comment: Do you actually have strings in the form `'month:12;year:2006'`? Not dictionaries? Do you mean to say that `M1[1]` is the end date, rather than `M2[0]`? Have you tried googling "python convert string to date" and "python get difference between dates"? Do you understand that you're asking two questions which could be asked and tackled separately?

Comment: I added 0 to be easy ini calculation 
Obviously i would be doing 
for anything thats against the forward slassh t1 = (2010-2006)*12
for anythng thats before the forward slash t2 = (4-0)
and then adding t = t1+t2

Comment: @AlexHall Thanks buddy i didn't know python had the built in functions for date also, using import datetime
Its really handy Thanks buddy I'm new to python. 
Python is love.

Comment: Can you please explain how `M2Diff` is `52` and `M3Diff` is `51`.  To me, they should be 46 and 52 .

Comment: Always google everything. You will be surprised at how often you get results.

Comment: It is very similar to this one I guess:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039879/best-way-to-find-the-months-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1):

I will show how to do it, for the first, in same way you can implement

```
def diff_month(d1, d2):
    return abs((d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month)


M1=['month:12;year:2006', 'month:7;year:2010']
d1 = datetime.strptime(M1[0], 'month:%m;year:%Y')
d2 = datetime.strptime(M1[1], 'month:%m;year:%Y')

diff_month(d1, d2)
```

In this method just use for loop for all the date collection.

Hope this helps