# List of months between two dates in python

Tags: python, date

I am using this code to find months between two dates:

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime(2017, 4, 30)
end_date = datetime(2017, 5, 6)
months = [dt.strftime("%m")
          for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=start_date,
                          until=end_date)]
In [14]: months
Out[14]: ['04']
```

I was expecting ['04', '05']

For example if i change dates

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime(2017, 4, 30)
end_date = datetime(2017, 5, 30)
months = [dt.strftime("%m")
          for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=start_date,
                          until=end_date)]

In [42]: months
Out[42]: ['04', '05']
```

Comment: Technically there are no months between the dates in your question. Anyway what does `rrule` do?

Comment: `rrule` is not specified. Please provide a full runable example including imports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to find the months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039879/best-way-to-find-the-months-between-two-dates)

Comment: The `rrule` object with monthly frequency can only yield one datetime since `start_date` and `end_date` are less than one month appart. What else do you expect?

Comment: only in this case i have this error, in other ones it works fine

Comment: I didn't realize that there was less than one month ... thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY


start_date = datetime(2017,4,30)
end_date = datetime(2017,5,6)

oneMonth = relativedelta(months=1)

months = [dt.strftime("%m")
          for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=start_date,
                          until=end_date+oneMonth)]

print months
```

Output:

```
['04', '05']
```