# Find number of months between today and a dataframe date field in python polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'd like to find the number of months between today and a date field in a python polars dataframe.
How do you do that?

```
(datetime.today() - pl.col('mydate')).dt.days()
```

returns it only in days.

Comment: How do you define that difference (28 days, 30 days, 31 days)? What should be the difference between 21 July 2023 and 1 August 2023, for example? See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040338/9857631) is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it using the pl.date_ranges() function. This mimics the Excel DATEDIF formula. Essentially, you are creating a list of unique months between the start date and the end dates, then calculating the length of the list to find the months.

```
df.with_columns(diffInMonths=(pl.date_ranges(pl.col('Start Date'),pl.col('End Date'),'1mo',closed='right')).list.len())
```

This was the smoothest way for me to calculate the difference between two dates in months.

Be aware: pl.date_range() and pl.date_range**s**() do different things, so be sure to use the plural version.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with the same problem and didn’t really find an elegant polars solution yet. I ended up using plain old math logic by calculating `12 * year_difference + month_difference`. But beware, that polars cast the number to `u32` which is an unsigned integer and therefore if the subtraction of the months should give a negative number, then it will be wrong. Therefore, you need to cast the number manually to an integer. Here is some example code:

```
df = df.with_columns([
        (
                (
                        df.select('dateA').to_series().dt.year().cast(pl.Int16) -
                        df.select('dateB').to_series().dt.year().cast(pl.Int16)
                ) * 12 +
                (
                        df.select('dateA').to_series().dt.month().cast(pl.Int16) -
                        df.select('dateB').to_series().dt.month().cast(pl.Int16)
                )
        ).alias('delta_months')
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing `pip install polars-xdt` which will install Marco's 'eXtra stuff for DateTimes' [extension](https://marcogorelli.github.io/polars-xdt-docs/index.html).

It provides a lot of useful functionality for dealing with datetimes, including:

```
import polars_xdt as xdt 

df.with_columns(xdt.month_delta("my_date", "other_date").alias("month_delta"))
```

You can find specific documentation for month_delta [here](https://marcogorelli.github.io/polars-xdt-docs/api/polars_xdt.month_delta.html), but I think it does exactly what you want and it will be very fast (rust implementation). Obviously 'other_date' can easily be today by adding something like `pl.lit(today()).alias("other_date")` to your dataframe.